# How to delete black borders from undistorted image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, distortion

I've been looking for a response in other posts and trying several ways to get it but I couldn't find anything helping me.
I am working on image undistortion, the code used is as shown bellow but it doesn't give the result i am looking for:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
cbrow = 7
cbcol = 9

objp = np.zeros((cbrow * cbcol, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:cbcol, 0:cbrow].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = []  
imgpoints = []

CHECKERBOARD =  (7,9)

img = cv2.imread("ChessUOledVGA.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
print(corners)

if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        ## Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (cbcol, cbrow), corners2, ret)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0) 

 ret, mtx, dist , rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
        print('mtx', mtx)
        print('dist',dist)
        img = cv2.imread('ChessUOledVGA.jpg', 1)
        h, w = img.shape[:2]  # get the size and the shape of the image h,w
        newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))
        print('newcameramtx', newcameramtx)
        dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
        cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', dst)
```

When i run this code , i have an image not correctly undistorted , and with black borders like it is shown here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMA5t.jpg)

And this is the original image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGtIE.jpg)
Could someone help me please.
Thanks

Comment: Black pixels are just filler, an image is always a rectangle and each pixel in this 2d array must have a value. Opencv seems assigning black color to these pixels. Your problem is not black borders, actual problem is your undistortion is not working correctly.

Comment: Thank you @unlut for your prompt reply and for the explanation. I understand what you said. Otherwise , would you mind if i ask you to have a look at my code and guide me to find whta it doesn't word correctly in my undistortion. Thanks

Comment: When creating object points, you used rows and columns in wrong order. Try objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:cbrow, 0:cbcol].T.reshape(-1,2)

Comment: I tried the modification you recommanded and it worked. I didn't pay attention to this error , thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi @unlut , Thank you for your help. I have one more question please. What could make this code work for one chessboard picture and not for an other.  Knowing that the other chessboard picture have the same dimensions .

Comment: It is hard to answer, when you say "not work", do you get a completely wrong result like in this question, or your result quality is not very good. Maybe you should ask a separate question.

Comment: When I said it doesn't work i meant to say that the chessboard corners are not detected , therfore matrix and distortion coefficients are not calculated. When i run the code it doesn't give any error but it does not return the image with corners detected . Thank you @unlut , yes i did ask a separate question this is the link  [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128995/what-could-make-undistortion-code-not-work-for-several-chessboard-images-having/65130272#65130272 ]  , maybe it would seem clear to you and could help me.