# What could make undistortion code not work for several chessboard images having the same dimensions?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, distortion

I am beginner in OpenCV-Python. I would like to know what could make my undistortion code work for this chessboard picture

[image]

and not work for this one

[image]

knowing that the too chessboards have the same dimension.

The code i am talking about is as below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
cbrow = 7
cbcol = 9

objp = np.zeros((cbrow * cbcol, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:cbcol, 0:cbrow].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = []  
imgpoints = []

CHECKERBOARD =  (7,9)

img = cv2.imread("ChessUOledVGA.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
print(corners)

if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        ## Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (cbcol, cbrow), corners2, ret)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0) 

 ret, mtx, dist , rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
        print('mtx', mtx)
        print('dist',dist)
        img = cv2.imread('ChessUOledVGA.jpg', 1)
        h, w = img.shape[:2]  # get the size and the shape of the image h,w
        newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))
        print('newcameramtx', newcameramtx)
        dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
        cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', dst)
```

Could someone enlighten me please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkboard dimensions must be (no of corners per row, no of corners per col) ->(9,7). And, you should threshold your image before passing into the find corners function as there is shades in four corners of the problematic image. Try this, it works.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
cbrow = 7
cbcol = 9

objp = np.zeros((cbrow * cbcol, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:cbcol, 0:cbrow].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = []  
imgpoints = []

CHECKERBOARD =  (9,7)

img = cv2.imread("ChessUOledVGA.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, out = cv2.threshold(gray, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(out, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
print(corners, ret)

if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners2)
    ## Draw and display the corners
    img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (cbcol, cbrow), corners2, ret)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0) 

if 0:
    ret, mtx, dist , rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
    print('mtx', mtx)
    print('dist',dist)
    img = cv2.imread('ChessUOledVGA.jpg', 1)
    h, w = img.shape[:2]  # get the size and the shape of the image h,w
    newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))
    print('newcameramtx', newcameramtx)
    dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
    cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', dst)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer , i did try what you said but still doesn't work, the code is correctly compiled but i don't get the chessboard corners detected , therfore the matrix and distortion coefficients are not calculated. I think the problem is in the cv2.findChessboardCorners function , because  i kept only the code from the start till the `print ( corners, ret) `  and i deleted everything else  but still no result. I don't know what to do to get my corners detected.

Comment: @Y.OU This answer leads to correct result but reasoning is not totally correct. It is not because (7,9) or (9,7) because. What changes things is the thresholding. Main problem with your input image is lightning. Since your image is so dark, even the value of white pixels which is supposed to be ~255 is below 100 (some are even around 50). Before calling findChessboardCorners you can threshold the gray image as ret, gray_thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 35, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) and use this thresholded gray image in findChessboardCorners. Also remove thresholding from findChessboardCorners func.

Comment: @unlut Thank you so much for your explanations , your answers are so helpful. I understand now what was the problem and i tried what you suggested it works correctly and i get the image corners detected.